# I can't get the position of a game object into a vector3 variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see I am trying to create a vector3 variable that stores the position of the gameobject and I'm getting the following error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

I have tried turning the gameobject into static variable but then I get another error inside Unity:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

How can I fix this?

```
public GameObject playerobject;

private Vector3 playerposition = playerobject.transform.position;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the `playerposition` in a function instead of where it is declared. The `Start` or `Awake` function is fine for this. If you need to update the `playerposition` variable every frame then do it in the `Update` function. The reason for this is that the variable you use to initialize another variable **outside** a function must be a `static` or `const` variable.

I am sure you don't want the `playerobject` to be `static` or `const` because you want to assign it in the Editor so doing it in a function is the correct way to do this.

```
public GameObject playerobject;
private Vector3 playerposition;

void Awake()
{
    playerposition = playerobject.transform.position;
}
```

After that, make sure to apply an Object to thethe `playerobject` slot in the Editor.

Comment: Thank you so much!